# How to use gghighlight when also using ggplot, geom_line and group

Tags: r, ggplot2, highlight, group, gghighlight

I can't figure out to plot my data using geom_line and geom_point so that gghighlight works without needing the variables to be in the global environment

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gghighlight)
```

**Create some data**

```
x <- rep(1:5, 4)
y <- c(rep(1:5, 1) + rnorm(5)/5, rep(1:5, 1) + rnorm(5)/5 + 1, rep(6:10, 1) + rnorm(5)/5, rep(6:10, 1) + rnorm(5)/5 + 1)
treatment <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels=letters[1:2])
replicate <- gl(2, 5, 20, labels=letters[25:26])
d <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, treatment=treatment, replicate=replicate)
d
```

**Plot v1 is as desired**

```
v1 <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment, shape = replicate, group=interaction(treatment, replicate))) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) + geom_line()
v1
```

**gghighlight works here as required but only when the variables are in the global environment**

```
v1 + gghighlight(replicate == "y")
v1 + gghighlight(treatment == "a")

rm(replicate, treatment,x,y)

v1 + gghighlight(replicate == "y")
v1 + gghighlight(treatment == "a")
```

**if the global variables are removed I get this error message**

```
Error in `f()`:
! Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): shape = replicate. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: Tried to calculate with group_by(), but the calculation failed.
Falling back to ungrouped filter operation... 
2: Using `across()` in `filter()` is deprecated, use `if_any()` or `if_all()`. 
3: Tried to calculate with group_by(), but the calculation failed.
Falling back to ungrouped filter operation... 
4: Using `across()` in `filter()` is deprecated, use `if_any()` or `if_all()`. `
```

**Try alternative ways of generating the plot**

```
v2 <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment, shape = replicate)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + geom_line()
v2
```

**Highlighting does not work**

```
v2 + gghighlight(replicate == "y")
v2 + gghighlight(treatment == "a")
```

**Third version of plot**

```
v3 <- ggplot(d) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment, shape = replicate), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment, shape = replicate))
v3
```

**Highlight occurs but goes wrong**

```
v3 + gghighlight(replicate == "y")
v3 + gghighlight(treatment == "a")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies with you mapping the `shape` aesthetic in the main `ggplot` call, instead of specifying it within the `geom_point` call. The `gghighlight` function creates a new data frame for each layer with the required aesthetic values, and this process doesn't work properly if there is unrecognised aesthetic data in a layer. `geom_line` doesn't have a `shape` aesthetic, so the `replicate` column in the plot's main data frame is not filtered during the creation of the `geom_line` layer and is therefore a different length from the filtered data.

The solution is to create the plot like this:

```r
v1 <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y, colour = treatment, 
                    group = interaction(treatment, replicate))) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = replicate), size = 3) + 
  geom_line()
```

So now you can do:

```r
rm(replicate, treatment,x,y)

v1 + gghighlight(replicate == "y")
```

[image]

and

```r
v1 + gghighlight(treatment == "a")
```

[image]